# C: issues with fscanf (repetitive output)

Tags: c, file, scanf

I am quite new in C programming. I tried the following code which will simply print the information in console from a file named **"student_data.txt"**. The code is here:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE* fp;

    fp = fopen("student_data.txt", "r");
    if (!fp)
    {
        perror("Error: ");
        return 1;
    }

    /*
    The file is this:
    id 1
    name abc
    total_gpa 9.55
    hsc 4.55
    ssc 5.0

    id 2
    name def
    total_gpa 9.55
    hsc 5.0
    ssc 4.55

    id 3
    name xyz
    total_gpa 8.00
    Alevel 4.0
    Olevel 4.0

    id 4
    name pqr
    total_gpa 10
    hsc 5.0
    ssc 5.0

    id 5
    name ali
    total_gpa 9.67
    hsc 4.67
    ssc 5.0

    id 6
    name hasan
    total_gpa 7.5
    Alevel 3.5
    Olevel 4.0

    id 7
    name kamal
    total_gpa 7.5
    Alevel 4.0
    Olevel 3.5
    
    */

    char input[10][30];

    while(!feof(fp))
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            fscanf(fp, "%s", input[i]);
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            printf("%s ", input[i]);
            if(i % 2 == 1)
            {
                printf("\n");
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    fclose(fp);
}
```

When I run the code, the output shows for the information of **id 7** twice. I have no idea how to solve the problem. Is there any problem with the while loop?

```
.....

id 7
name kamal
total_gpa 7.5
Alevel 4.0
Olevel 3.5

id 7
name kamal
total_gpa 7.5
Alevel 4.0
Olevel 3.5
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fscanf returns the amount of matches it could find, which in your case always has to be 1, meaning if it's not 1 you can stop.

This should fix it:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE* fp;

    fp = fopen("student_data.txt", "r");
    if (!fp)
    {
        perror("Error: ");
        return 1;
    }

    char input[10][30];

    while(1)
    {
        bool end = false;
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            if (fscanf(fp, "%s", input[i]) != 1){
                end = true;
            }
        }

        if (end) break;

        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            printf("%s ", input[i]);
            if(i % 2 == 1)
            {
                printf("\n");
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    fclose(fp);
}
```